# Extract random sample of N lines based on pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, random

I have a file formatted like this:

```
train/t/temple/east_asia/00000025.jpg 94
train/t/temple/east_asia/00000865.jpg 94
...
train/s/swamp/00000560.jpg 92
train/s/swamp/00000935.jpg 92
....
train/m/mountain/00000428.jpg 68
train/m/mountain/00000126.jpg 68
```

The last number is the class number. I have 50 different classes, and each class has 1,000 lines. I would like to take a random sample of size N from each class, and store the result in another text file.

Comment: Are lines grouped by class ?

Comment: Yes, indeed that is correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your lines are grouped by class, you could (with `gnu` tools)`split` the file into pieces and use the `--fiter` option to pipe each piece to `shuf` to extract *N* random lines from it:

```
split --filter='shuf -n N' infile > outfile
```

Note that `split` defaults to 1000 lines - which is what you need in this particular case. If the requirements change you'll have to pass the number of lines via `-l`
e.g. to split into pieces of 200 lines and extract 30 random lines from each piece:

```
split -l 200 --filter='shuf -n 30' infile > outfile
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution :) I cant upvote you since I don't have enough points, sorry about that!

Comment: That looks like a UUOC; am I missing something?

Comment: Note that GNU `split` invokes `$SHELL` instead of `sh` to parse that `shuf -n 30` command line. So you can speed it up by doing `SHELL=/bin/sh split...`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with just one `awk` command invocation:

To select p=50 lines at random out of every n=1000 lines:

```
awk -v n=1000 -v p=50 '
  BEGIN {srand(); remaining = p}
  NR > n {remaining = p; NR = 1}
  rand()*(n + 1 - NR) < remaining {
    print; remaining--
  }' < your-file
```